# Gen2 Cloud Functions Triggered by Pub/Sub and HTTPS - Receiving Undefined Request in HTTP Trigger

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, curl

I have a Google Cloud Function (Gen2) that is primarily triggered by Pub/Sub messages. I want to extend its functionality so that it can also be triggered by HTTPS requests. However, I'm encountering an issue where the request object (`req`) is undefined when triggered via HTTPS.

Here is a snippet of my function:

```js
exports.main = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    let data
    if(req.data){ // if pubsub message
        const pubSubMessage = req
        data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubSubMessage.data, 'base64').toString())
    }else{ // if https request
        data = req.body
    }

    console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
    const { url, instructions } = data
    // ... rest of the function
}
```

When the function is triggered by a Pub/Sub message, everything works as expected, and data contains the expected information. However, when I attempt to trigger the function via an HTTPS request using curl or Postman (with the correct authorization token), the req object is logged as undefined.

I'm sending my HTTPS requests like this:

```bash
curl -X POST https://[FUNCTION_URL] \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"url":"https://example.com","instructions": [...] }'
```

I've ensured that the URL is correct, the method is POST, the token is valid, and the request body is a valid JSON.

Any insights into why the req object is undefined in the case of HTTPS triggers and how I can resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a JSON body sample that you use? (with redacted data)

Comment: thanks for you comment !

there you go (beautify):
{
    "url": "https://...",
    "instructions": [
        {
            "step": {
                "step": "open",
                "stepParameters": {
                    "url": "default"
                },
                "ordinance": 0
            },
            "tests": [
                {
                    "testType": "element",
                    "testParameters": {
                        "selector": "#custom"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Oh ok, you want to use the same endpoint for PubSub message format, but also for custom format. It should be possible, even if it's not a good idea. You should use 2 different endpoints. Anyway. Is your first log of the request correct?

Comment: Yes, Gen2 Cloud Functions support both HTTPS and Pub/Sub triggers on the same endpoint, which is exactly what I'm trying to leverage in my project. My goal is to use this function both as part of a sequence of cloud functions communicating via Pub/Sub and independently via HTTPS for one-shot executions.
The function works as expected when triggered by Pub/Sub with the provided code and JSON payload. It also functions correctly when executed locally through Postman. However, when I attempt to trigger the function via HTTPS using curl on GCP, the req object appears as 'undefined'

Comment: if there's no solution, i can create the function that'll work only for https endpoint for sure, but less challenging ;)

Comment: I guess you have to stick to CloudEvent format if you follow this Tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#preparing_the_application Keep in mind that your function code is wrapped in something you do not totally manage. If you want to have a better control on the runtime environment (and several endpoints) I recommend you to have a look to Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub Much similar to your code, and offer a better evolution https://medium.com/google-cloud/why-i-definitively-switched-from-cloud-functions-to-cloud-run-635d03f1eb4d

Comment: thanks for these link, i'll look at it !